# How to make an iframe with sandbox redirect inside the frame?

Tags: angularjs, redirect, iframe, sandbox

I currently have an app that contains an iframe with sandbox so it prevents the frame from accesing top-navigation like this:

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms allow-pointer-lock" class="iframe" ng-src="{{source_url}}"></iframe>
```

source_url contains an url "Y" that redirects to "X" where is shown what i need. The sandbox iframe prevent it to redirecting my whole app to site "X". The thing is that it also stop the frame from redirecting within it and shows me "Y", and i need the frame to show that site "X", is there a way to acomplish this? Is it viable to find a way to catch the attempt to redirect to "X" and change the iframe source_url?

Thanks a lot in advance, greetings!

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

This was a long time ago, so i might be a bit rusty on this, but my solution in the end was to leave the sandbox iframe(to keep preventing the frame from accesing top-navigation) but without initially loading the content using an ng-if, then extracting the url "X" i wanted to show on my controller and finally using [$sce.trustAsResourceUrl](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#) give the source_url to load the frame when it's needed.

Something like the following:

On my controller:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams, $http, $sce){
$scope.load_frame = false;
...
$scope.source_url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url_found);
```

And on my view

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms allow-pointer-lock" class="iframe" ng-if="load_frame" ng-src="{{source_url}}"></iframe>
```

So when i change the value of load_frame it loads the trusted url. Not the best, but at that moment was the fix i could pull off. Hopefully would help someone :)